# I am trying to print but not being able to figure out the right command

Tags: c

```
struct Name {                                  // structure
  char firstName[31];          
};

int main(void) {
  struct Name name;                            // structure type variable 
  void getName(struct Name *name);
  printf("First name: %s\n", name->firstName); //printing error occurring
}

void getName(struct Name *name) {               //function definition
  printf("Please enter the contact’s first name: ");
  scanf("%s", name->firstName);                //taking the input from user
}
```

In my code I am trying to create a contact management system. I have structure a function and a main function. What I am doing is I have a structure, I am passing that structure to a function. The function gets an input for the structure member and stores it. But there's something wrong with my syntax while calling the `getName()` function and while printing the structure member input that I took from the user.

Comment: Should be printf("First name: %s\n", name.firstName); istead of name->firstName

Comment: right,thanks so much and how would I call the function?

Comment: This is a function prototype, not a call to that function. `void getName(struct Name*name);` Try `getName(&name);`

Comment: Yeah I need the syntax to call the function that I defined

Comment: Note that the declaration of `getName()` should not be buried inside another function (`main()` in the question).  Either define the function before it is called (so `main()` is last in the file), or put the declaration before `main()`.  It can then be used by other functions too — you will eventually be writing programs with many functions, and many of the functions will be called from multiple other functions.  Writing the prototypes of such shared functions inside each function that calls them would be silly — and would make maintenance of the code into a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the way you are accessing member of the object. It should be accessed like:
`name.firstName` instead of with -> operator. This is because you have an object and not a reference (pointer) to an object.

So the correct prints call is:

```
printf(“First Name: %s\n”, name.firstName);
```